# Java error "OpenCV Assertion failed: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S)"

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, contour, robotics

When I try to run this openCV code on an FTC robot:

```
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        Imgproc.findContours(thresholded, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        contoursAttr = contours;

        MatOfPoint biggestContour = new MatOfPoint();

        for (MatOfPoint curContour : contours) {
            if (Imgproc.contourArea(curContour) > Imgproc.contourArea(biggestContour)) {
                biggestContour = curContour;
            }
        }
```

I get the error in the title, namely "OpenCV Assertion failed: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S)". I've seen other answers for this question, but they almost all talk about signatures changing across versions, and are somewhat python-specific. However, given that `contours` is a `List<MatOfPoint>`, I feel like this should work??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first iteration of the loop, `biggestContour` is created using default constructor, and has the wrong OpenCV depth.

The following code creates `MatOfPoint` object with default constructor:

```
MatOfPoint biggestContour = new MatOfPoint();
```

In the first iteration, the following code computes `contourArea` over the "new" `MatOfPoint`:

```
if (Imgproc.contourArea(curContour) > Imgproc.contourArea(biggestContour)
```

The result is the error "OpenCV Assertion failed... && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S)"
The reason for getting the specific assertion is because the depth of the "new" `MatOfPoint` is `CV_8UC1` (not `CV_32F` and not `CV_32S`).

---

Suggested solution:
Initialize `biggestContour` to the first contour in the list:

```
MatOfPoint biggestContour = contours.get(0); //new MatOfPoint();

for (MatOfPoint curContour : contours) {
    if (Imgproc.contourArea(curContour) > Imgproc.contourArea(biggestContour)) {
        biggestContour = curContour;
    }
}
```

---

It is also a good practice to verify that `contours` is not empty:

```
if (!contours.isEmpty())
{
    MatOfPoint biggestContour = contours.get(0);//new MatOfPoint();
    
    for (MatOfPoint curContour : contours) {
        if (Imgproc.contourArea(curContour) > Imgproc.contourArea(biggestContour)) {
            biggestContour = curContour;
        }
    }
}
```